# Update table without refreshing after adding an item in reactjs

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, async-await

I'm developing an application in react.Js

And I have a table that I need to update without having to refresh the page.

The code:

```
const App = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState([])
    const [category, setCategory] = useState([])

    const categories = category.map(elem => ({
        value: elem.id,
        label: elem.cat,
    }));

    const [category_select, setCategorySelect] = React.useState(null);

    function handleChangeCategory(value) {
        setCategorySelect(value);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems()
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategories()
    }, [])

    const getItems = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(REQUEST_1)
        setItem(response.data)
    }

    const getCategories = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(REQUEST_2)
        setCategory(response.data)
    }

    const addItems = () => {
        axios.post(`${REQUEST_1}`, {cat: category_select.value});
    };

    const body = () => {
        return item && item.map((elem,j) => {
            return (
                <tr key={elem.id}>
                    <td><span>{elem.cat}</span></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <NoSsr>
                                <Select
                                    classes={classes}
                                    styles={selectStyles}
                                    inputId="category"
                                    TextFieldProps={{
                                        label: 'Category',
                                        InputLabelProps: {
                                        htmlFor: 'category',
                                        shrink: true,
                                        },
                                        placeholder: 'Search',
                                    }}
                                    options={categories}
                                    components={components}
                                    value={category}
                                    onChange={handleChangeCategory}
                                />
                            </NoSsr>
                            <span>Select</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <span onClick={addItems}></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <span>Category</span>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {body()}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```

The idea is that a category is selected and the item is added.

What I need is to be able to update the map (`return item && item.map((elem,j) => {...})`) after clicking on `<span onClick={addItems}></span>` which calls the `addItems` function that adds the item. Simply put I need it to be added in the table without having to update.

How can I do it, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the dependency to the `useEffect` so that every time the user wants adds an item, `getItems()` request is called to get the new items. So, your code might look like something like this:

```
const App = () => {
    const [item, setItem] = useState([])
    const [category, setCategory] = useState([])
    const [addedItem, setAddedItem] = useState('')
    
    
    const categories = category.map(elem => ({
        value: elem.id,
        label: elem.cat,
    }));

    const [categorySelect, setCategorySelect] = React.useState(null);

    function handleChangeCategory(value) {
        setCategorySelect(value);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getItems()
    }, [addedItem])

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategories()
    }, [])

    const getItems = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(REQUEST_1)
        setItem(response.data)
    }

    const getCategories = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get(REQUEST_2)
        setCategory(response.data)
    }

    const addItems = () => {
        const response = await axios.post(`${REQUEST_1}`, {cat: category_select.value});
        setAddedItem(response.data)
    };

    const body = () => {
        return item && item.map((elem,j) => {
            return (
                <tr key={elem.id}>
                    <td><span>{elem.cat}</span></td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <NoSsr>
                                <Select
                                    classes={classes}
                                    styles={selectStyles}
                                    inputId="category"
                                    TextFieldProps={{
                                        label: 'Category',
                                        InputLabelProps: {
                                        htmlFor: 'category',
                                        shrink: true,
                                        },
                                        placeholder: 'Search',
                                    }}
                                    options={categories}
                                    components={components}
                                    value={category}
                                    onChange={handleChangeCategory}
                                />
                            </NoSsr>
                            <span>Select</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>&nbsp;</label>
                            <span onClick={addItems}></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <div>
                                <table>
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>
                                                <span>Category</span>
                                            </th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        {body()}
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default App;
```